# Migration tool for appsettings.json config

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, appsettings

I have a hosted asp.net core project. And every time a new version has to be deployed and its **appsettings** config has some structural changes (added new keys or renamed some old config keys for example) - I need to manually add/rename these new keys in the existing production configuration. Is there any tool that allows creating config migrations and then running them to update existing config files (something like entity framework migration system for DB structure changes but for appsettings.json config)?

Comment: Why isn't the appsettings.json or appsettings.<env>.json file not deployed with the rest of the application?

Comment: You should deploy your production configuration alongside your project. If there are sensitive bits and bobs to your production configuration a CI/CD pipeline should manage those pieces.